# PHP parsing on includes

Tags: php, parsing, include

I'm including a file **init.php** which defines path constants. So if I include **init.php** in a file (**index.php**) and then in another file (**layout/header.php**)... is **init.php** parsed before being added to these files or is it added to the parent file and then the parent file is parsed as a whole?

EDIT: Why this is important is because **init.php** defines path variables relative to location of where it is parsed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `include` and `require` are identical in all except `require` will fail with `E_ERROR` while `include` will issue a warning. Also both of the statements are only activated when they actually executed inside script. So the following code will always work:

```
<?php
echo "Hello world";
if (0) require "non_existing.php";
```

The answer to your question is that `index.php` will be parsed first and executed. Then when `include "init.php"` encountered the file `init.php` is parsed and executed within current scope. The same for `layout/header.php` - it will be parsed first.

As already noted `init.php` will be parsed and executed each time `include` / `require` is called, so you probably will want to use `include_once` or `require_once`.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it as being copy-pasted into the file at the position where it was included. Use `require_once` or `include_once` if you don't want your stuff redefined.

---

There is no difference between including a `.php` or a `.txt`. You can include php in a `.txt` file and it will get parsed as long as you have the `<?php` openning tag.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you use `include` or `require`. With `include` the text content of the included file is added to the parent and then the whole thing is parsed. With `require` the included file is first parsed and its content made available to the runtime, then processing continues with parsing the rest of the containing file.

If you want to make sure that the init file is only loaded once in a runtime of a request, then use `require_once` to make sure that it is only parsed once regardless of how many times you call it. Its a good idea to try to load your init file everywhere you need its constants, but use `require_once` to make sure you don't parse it more times then needed.

Comment: pingw33 is correct - `require` and `include` defer only in the severity of failure.

Comment: Also no text inclusion is performed, every php file is parsed as is.