# Blade: extending a template in multiple subviews

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Blade to include multiple sub-views into a single set of tabs in a blade app.  All of the sub-views have the same overall structure (a sidebar and a main section).  Because of this, I have created a template and each sub-view extends the template.  Here is the structure:

**Main.blade.php**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    @foreach($views as $view)
    <li><a href="#{{$view}}">{{$view}}</a></li>
    @endforeach
  </ul>
  @foreach($views as $view)
  <div id="{{$view}}">
    @include($view)
  </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

**template.blade.php**

```
{{-- formatting stuff --}}
  @yield('content 1')
{{-- more formatting stuff --}}
  @yield('content-2')
{{-- more formatting stuff --}}
```

**tab-*.blade.php**

```
@extends('template')

@section('content-1')
This is tab [whatever number]
@stop

@section('content-2')
Lorem Ipsum
@stop
```

The obvious problem here is that, as each sub-view extends the same template, the `@yield('content')` exists 3 times, and all 3 included sub-views have their own `@section('content')`.  What appears to be happening is that the first sub-view's implementation of the content section is getting placed in all 3 yields.

My intent here is obvious.  I want each included sub-view to implement it's own instance of the template, place it's content in the content section, **THEN** get pulled into the main page.  Can this be done?

If I flatten the **tab-*.blade.php** files and stop using the template, it works fine.  The problem here is that I end up with a lot of code repetition that would be better placed in a template.  This is an emergency option, but I'd like to do it the "proper" way.

**NOTE**

I have tried to redesign this to avoid the problem, but I really can't come up with another solution.  While `@include` is typically used to pull in small, static pieces (a header, a footer, etc.), I have not read anything that states this as a restriction.  It seems to me that the best approach is to store each view once and pull them into the main page when needed, so that's how I've designed it.

Comment: Also standard PHP include function does do *top-bottom* parsing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1376481/php-parsing-on-includes Extending is the opposite to it, the *bottom-up* mechanism, but you seem to refuse it.

Comment: @msturdy yes that is a typo.  the actual code does use `@yield`.  Fixed now

Comment: @delmadord When simply swapping `@include` for `@extends`, the page completely restructures itself.  The contend that it supposed to be part of the tab now appears at the top of the page ABOVE the tab headers, and it now displays the LAST included tab, rather than the first.  It still does not switch properly.

Comment: @delmadord  I guess I'm just not getting what you're going for.  can you, using exactly the code I provided above, post an exact and complete replacement that will do what I'm looking for?  maybe I just need to see the example.

Comment: Unfortunately what?  The example posted is complete, but doesn't work the way I hope.  Can you not write a complete demonstration using `@extends` of how the exact same page could be created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with a hack that seems to work.  In **template.blade.php**, I use the following:

```
{{-- formatting stuff --}}
  @yield(isset($tab) ? "content-1-$tab" : 'content-1')
{{-- more formatting stuff --}}
  @yield(isset($tab) ? "content-2-$tab" : 'content-2')
{{-- more formatting stuff --}}
```

Then, in **main.blade.php**, I execute `@include('view', ['tab'=>$view])`.  This seems to cause each instance of `content-1` and `content-2` do be named distinctly, allowing the 2 subviews to implement the sections separately.  This also should allow any other views that implement this template to continue to function without having to change anything.

Answer (score 8):

Try using the `@overwrite` command instead of `@stop`

Example:

```
@extends('template')

@section('content-1')
     Stuff goes here...
@overwrite

@section('content-2')
     More stuff goes here...
@overwrite
```

Source: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1058#issuecomment-17194530